# Using Storyboard With View Controllers

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm new to iOS development, but I know the coding. I want to do ios app which has 6 or 7 views. I want to use one storyboard and 6 or 7 views. I have to pass data between these views. I need a tutorial. I searched about it on google, but I could not find anything as I want to. Thanks for sharing any piece of code or tutorial.

Comment: Here is series of storyboard tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're having? Apple has a storyboard tutorial called "Your Second App" -- is that not sufficient?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using storyboard , You need to make 6 or 7 controllers as you are saying.

This [link](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/) may help you in passing data across these controllers.

Comment: My question is also down voted, It is not understandable. Thanks for attention.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, but FWIW, a downvote != wrong answer.  A downvote can indicate that a link-only answer should have included more information directly in the answer (e.g. a summary of how to pass data, not just the link to another site.)  Consider that if the linked-to site goes away, your answer itself has no other helpful information about passing data.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked many, many times before. First, read the Apple-supplied docs about view controllers. Then refer to this question and its answer:

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)